# How to send and receive large amounts of data in udp c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, visual-c++, udp

I am trying to send and receive large amounts of data at once in udp c++, with the following code. I can send at once just 16000 bits, char. How can one send/receive millions of bytes of data without closing the socket?

```
//sends the data contained in aliceBuf, which is, char of size 16000. 

if (sendto(aliceSocket, aliceBuf, strlen(aliceBuf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bobAddr, sizeof (bobAddr)) == -1) {
    perror("sendto");
    exit(1);
}
```

---

```
// receiver code: it is receiving just 16000 char.

recvlen = recvfrom(aliceSocket, aliceBuf1, receiveBuffer, 0, (struct  sockaddr*)&bobAddr,  &bobAddrSize);

if (recvlen >= 0) {
    aliceBuf1[recvlen] = 0; /* expect a printable string - terminate it */
}
```

Comment: Send/receive smaller packets in a loop?

Comment: As for your problem, you have to remember that there are many buffers in the layers between your application and the wire (or radio), those buffers have a finite, often quite small, size. Trying to write more than fits in the buffers will give you errors (and the errors will tell you exactly what is wrong).

Comment: Also remember that the actual packets sent over the wire (or radio) is much smaller than the buffers, so the network stack has to split the data up. Sending smaller packets from the application will skip that splitting/reassembling of packets, which of course is more effective.

Comment: when I run with large size, the console blinks and disspaears without showing any error. the functions sendto and recvfrom are not just accepting bigger size datas, in my case 16000 char bits. I need to send more than 1M bits for comparision. can you please suggest me How can I send and accept the smaller data packets in a loop.

Comment: You need to learn your terminology, you don't send "char bits", you send *bytes*. Also, it's very probable that the buffer sizes are not exactly 16000 but 16384. And what errors do you get?

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg says.  You have to split your buffer up into more than one datagram.  There is no alternative with your buffer sizes and UDP. None at all.

Comment: Pay attentions, that even if you'll split your data in small datagramms, but if you'll send them over UDP **faster** then receiver can get them - you'll have omissions

Answer (score 1):

You can send a large amount of data in one go, but the question you have to ask yourself is: How will the receiver know how much data to expect?

I normally handle these cases by either encoding the length explicitly by prefixing the data with the length and then the receiver loops until that amount of data has arrived, or by having some sort of end of data marker like 'C' strings or more implicitly like json data and the receiver loops looking for something in the data itself.

Comment: I can send/receive 16384 char buffer in one go, i.e 16384 bits if I represent bits as char data type. more than this amount I couldnot receive. How Can we program the receiver to receive more than this amount through loop.Which is what I could not understand.

Comment: Each call to `recvfrom` returns a length. You can repeatedly call this function, each time appending the data to a main buffer, until the buffer is the right length.

Comment: @Hum you cannot send 1M bits in a single UDP datagram, no matter how you twiddle with your network stack config.  Datagrams have a 16-bit length field, so you can only send ~64k bytes, or ~512K bits, in one datagram.

Answer (score 0):

You wil have to add a protocol on top of UDP, just as if you were using TCP.  I'm sorry that you have to do some work, but that's just how things are.  Some of the datagrams may get lost, so you may have to add a layer for that too.  1M bits is ~twice as large as the largest possible UDP datagram anyway, so even if you reconfigure your network stack to allow larger datagrams, you will still hit the 64k limit, so requiring a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I did with loopiing like this:

```
   int totalGoLength= no of blocks you want to send 
   int dataLengthOneGo = length of data in one block you want to send
  //start loop
    int iii=1 ;
    while (iii <= totalGoLength){ //send by dividing into packets

////--SEND/by converting to char * for less memory occupation----
// theString has the string  data to send

    std::string part(theString.substr(0, dataLengthOneGo)); 
     char * s4;
     s4 = new char[part.size() + 1];
     memcpy(s4, part.c_str(), part.size() + 1);

    if (sendto(aliceSocket, s4, strlen(s4), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bobAddr, sizeof (bobAddr)) == -1) {
        perror("sendto");
        exit(1);
    }
        delete [] s4;

        ////----------------------Receiving------------
    // receive buffer should have sufficient memory allocation
          char *aliceBuf1;
      aliceBuf1 = new char[receiveBuffer];
      recvlen = recvfrom(aliceSocket, aliceBuf1, receiveBuffer, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bobAddr, &bobAddrSize);
    if (recvlen >= 0) {
        aliceBuf1[recvlen] = 0; /* expect a printable string - terminate it */

        //convert char to string
        string s1(aliceBuf1);
        //erase the white space
        s1.erase(remove_if(s1.begin(), s1.end(), isspace), s1.end());
        //convert string into integer vector
        std::vector<int> ints;
        ints.reserve(s1.size());
        std::transform(std::begin(s1), std::end(s1), std::back_inserter(ints), [](char c) {
            return c - '0'; });
    }
    delete[] aliceBuf1;

    justCopy=ints;
    KeepData.insert(KeepData.end(),justCopy .begin(), justCopy.end());
    justCopy.erase(justCopy.begin(), justCopy.end()); //erase for next time
    ints.erase(ints.begin(), ints.end()); //erase for next time
    theString.erase(theString.begin(), theString.begin() + dataLengthOneGo);//keep the remaining

    iii=iii+1;
}//end of the while
```